# Is it possible to append HEADERS using Response.Redirect?

Tags: c#, iis-6

Can I make a `Response.Redirect` modifying the headers of that "request (¿) "

Comment: What keeps you from redirecting in the response? (Differently put: What makes you want to "redirect" in the request?)

Comment: my Q has no sense at all, sorry, i realise now =), its a Response, not a request... thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to send a redirect and make the browser add headers to its HTTP request for the page you redirected to.

However, look at [`Server.Transfer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx).